# Trying to use extension in seleniumbase

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webautomation, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumbase

I'm trying to use some extensions while automating the browser with seleniumbase.

```
    with SB(uc=True,browser='chrome',headed=True,extension_zip='path/to/extension') as sb:
        sb.set_window_rect(pos_x,pos_y,500,720)
        sb.open('https://google.com')
        sleep(1000)
```

But there is no extension running when the task perform.
Using command method work expectedly:

```
pytest test.py --extension-zip=path/to/extension --headed
```

Since i cannot find the right way to use the `extension_zip` in python, can someone show me the way to work with it.
Thanks.

Comment: https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/syntax_formats/#Overriding%20the%20driver%20via%20BaseCase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as mentioned in https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/1817#issuecomment-1480062929, you need to convert your `.crx` file to a `.zip` file, and then unzip the file to a folder. Then use `extension_dir=DIR` as an option. UC Mode uses undetected-chromedriver, which doesn't support zipped/CRX extensions.